# Invalid Syntax on "def sleeper"

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, servo

I am working on a small project involving servos on the `Raspberry Pi`.
I wanted the servos to run for x amount of time then stop. Was trying out my code and am currently getting Invalid syntax on `"def sleeper"` and have no idea why.

Also being new to Stackoverflow, I had some issues indenting the code, my apologies!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)

try:
                while True:
                        GPIO.output(7,1)
                        time.sleep(0.0015)
                        GPIO.output(7,0)




def sleeper():
    while True:

        num = input('How long to wait: ')

        try:
            num = float(num)
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter in a number.\n')
            continue

        print('Before: %s' % time.ctime())
        time.sleep(num)
        print('After: %s\n' % time.ctime())


try:
    sleeper()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n\nKeyboard exception received. Exiting.')
    exit()
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't wrote any `except` block for the first `try ... except` pair:

This may work as you want:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)

try:
    while True:
        GPIO.output(7,1)
        time.sleep(0.0015)
        GPIO.output(7,0)
except:
    pass

def sleeper():
    while True:
        num = input('How long to wait: ')
        try:
            num = float(num)
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter in a number.\n')
            continue

    print('Before: %s' % time.ctime())
    time.sleep(num)
    print('After: %s\n' % time.ctime())

try:
    sleeper()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n\nKeyboard exception received. Exiting.')
    exit()
```

*Check indentations please.*

Comment: @TGFoxy You may want to accept my answer as a accepted answer by clicking on the Tick mark at the left side of the answer :)